# Turning computer on log?

Tags: security, log

Is there a way to find out when my computer was turned on even if user was not successful on logging in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look in the `syslog` files in `/var/log/` to see when the kernel was booted. Some of the older copies are compressed, or deleted over time, due to log rotation. Searching for `Command line:` in the files will give you timestamps of when the system was booted into Ubuntu.